# Perform bad blocks scan on root partition in Linux

Tags: linux, partitioning, ext3, fsck

My root partition is formatted as ext3 and I would like to perform a bad blocks scan on it. Normally *e2fsck -c -c* does this, but you can not run it on a mounted partition. I know it is possible to force a fsck to run at boot by creating the file */forcefsck* but is it possible to specify that it should also check for bad blocks? If not, what is the recommended way to check for bad blocks on the root partition? I would like to avoid having to create a rescue disk and boot off of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your init scripts support it (Fedora IIRC), you can add `-c -c` to `/fsckoptions` (then create `/forcefsck` and reboot).
Unfortunately, this feature isn't available everywhere. You probably have to reboot to a LiveCD/LiveUSB instead.

Answer (score 5):

See [Can I run fsck or e2fsck when Linux file system is mounted?](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/can-i-run-fsck-or-e2fsck-when-linux-file-system-is-mounted/), which notes that running any fsck on a mounted filesystem can result in disk or data corruption.

It suggests the following solutions:

**A.** Take down system to single user mode, unmount system, then run e2fsck

```
init 1
umount /dev/sda
e2fsck -y /dev/sda3
```

**B.** Boot from the installation CD into rescue mode

```
boot: linux rescue nomount<br/>
mknod /dev/sda
mknod /dev/sda3
fsck /dev/sda3
```

Another solution would be to use fsck to check the entire disk (except swap) on boot time, as root:

```
shutdown -Fr now
```

where -F stands for force fsck check and -r for reboot.

Comment: _shutdown_ seems to be missing the -F flag in my Fedora 13 and 14 installs. It would probably not use the "-c -c" option in any case.

Comment: -F seems available on Fedora : see [here](http://labtestproject.com/logout_reboot_shutdown_linux_fedora_core). Did you do this as root?

Comment: Actually I only checked the man page and the output of _shutdown --help_ neither which list -F. I should file a bug about that.

Comment: The reason for not documenting the -F option seems to be that the option does nothing. Possibly the command does not complain about the invalid switch to be backwards compatible with old scripts.

Answer (score 2):

You can boot the system and specify `init=/bin/bash` as boot parameter. This will run bash at boot and not the regular startup scripts. As a result no filesystems are processed and you are left with a read-only root.

Now you have a read-only root and you can fsck it.

Answer (score 1):

For unmounted filesystem, I also use:

```
dd if=/dev/diskdevice of=/dev/null
```

To check is any error while reading.

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
cat /dev/diskdevice >/dev/null
```

and then check what is in dmesg. If there is a bad block, it will say. The repair is another long story.